# How to add "Return Product" after "Product Delivery" functionality in Django Oscar

Tags: django, django-views, django-oscar

I want to add "Return Product" after "Product Delivery"  functionality in Django Oscar. in `settings.py` i added below code.

```
OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE = {
'Pending': ('Processing', 'Cancelled',),
'Processing': ('Shipped', 'Cancelled',),
'Shipped': ('Delivered', 'Return', 'Returned', 'Cancelled',),
'Returned': ('Return', 'Returned',),
'Delivered': (),
'Cancelled': (),
}

OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_CASCADE = {
  'Processing': 'In progress',
  'Shipped': 'Shipped',
  'Delivered': 'Delivered',
  'Returned': 'Returned',
 'Cancelled': 'Cancelled'
}
```

i have written Ajax function to change the status after Order gets "Delivered" to "Return". below is the function.

```
@csrf_exempt
def return_order(request):
# Return Order after Delivery
  if request.is_ajax():
    data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(id=int(data))
        EventHandler().handle_order_status_change(order=order, new_status='Return')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'True', 'msg': 'OK'}))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'False', 'msg': 'Error'}))
```

I am geting Error something like this 
`'Return' is not a valid status for order 100213 (current status: 'Delivered')`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE` is to define the set of valid next statuses for an order. Each key in that dictionary is mapped to a list of statuses that an order can be changed to from that status.

In your case you have: `'Delivered': (),` - which means that there is no valid status that an order can be changed to after it is delivered. Delivered is a final status, as is Cancelled.

If you want to allow changing from `Delivered` to `Return` then you need to change this line to:

```
'Delivered': ('Return',),
```